# onDeviceReady() {...} has no method 'bind'

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2013, phonegap-build

I have a [very simple app](https://github.com/ray023/FindAFit) that works on my desktop.

When I test through Adobe PhoneGap Build, it throws an exception on the following line:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
```

The exception is as follows:

> onDeviceReady() {...} has no method 'bind'

Where "..." is the code found in the function onDeviceReady.

As best I can tell, when PhoneGap Build builds the project for Android, it does not use the scripts included in the merges/android folder.

I have tried manually copying over those files, but I am either doing it wrong or that's not the correct process because the error still occurs.

I test it on my Android Samsung Captivate (Firmware 2.3.5 and Gingerbread.UCKK4).

Am I missing a step in the build process that's supposed to include any necessary files for PhoneGap Build?

My process was as follows:

1. Create the project with the VS2013 "Blank App (Apache Cordova)" template
2. Add my code
3. Link my Adobe PhoneGap build account to the open source project
4. Tell PhoneGap to pull latest and build
5. Scan the QR Code and install the apk it downloads
6. Test the app
7. Get the error
8. Scratch my head
9. GoTo 2

Comment: have you tried removing `.bind(this)`?

Comment: Well @DawsonLoudon removing all "bind" references, fixed the problem for my Android device.  (haven't tested any others yet).  I'm confused because that piece of code was autogenerated by visual studio.  Which makes me think it needs to be used for something, right?  Or just remove it and forget about it?

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap Build will only use the files in the folder/subfolders containing your index.html and config.xml file.

Phonegap build does not support the /merge/ directory for platform specific files. You can create a file named ".pgbomit" in example /www/platform/. Then only the files in that folder that you specifically specify for a specific platform in the config.xml file will be included in the build.